# Making 3d models with 2d images in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, models

Is it possible to make 3d models from 2d photos taken? For eg, can I make a 3d model of a human if I take images of him from all angles(stitching them)? Is this possible in unity? Thank you( pardon me if I have worked the question wrongly, I am still a beginner)

Comment: no, it is not possible - at least not by any simple means. perhaps it would be possible with very, very advanced algorithms that you would have to write yourself. Unity is a game engine, not 3D modeling tool (like Maya, Blender, ...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are asking for is called "photogrammetry".

And yes, it's possible to use it in Unity, but you will need more than one software(I think that the real unity-based tools to do it won't be release before 2018 version), I have not tried it personally, but I suggest you to start from here:

https://unity3d.com/es/solutions/photogrammetry (the web)
https://unity3d.com/files/solutions/photogrammetry/Unity-Photogrammetry-Workflow_2017-07_v2.pdf (the real info PDF)

Keep in mind that won't be easy! :D

*Edit: I found this video on Youtube which is really a photogrammetry in Unity tutorial from zero to hero! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ni42IOyePpY*